# How to get total size of HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I want monitor the response size in a servlet, so I plan to add filter to implement this function.

But I don't know how to get the response size when I check `HttpServletResponse` methods:

```
response.getWriter()
response.getOutputStream()
```

Is there any efficient way to calculate the total response size?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the response header, you can read the Content-Length. For example,

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Fri, 10 Mar 2015 14:00:00 GMT
Content-Length:728
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I just do some debug, and only can get 3 header. Content-Type|Transfer-Encoding|Date. Cannot find Content-Length in HttpServletResponse.

Comment: @Bensson: if neither you servlet nor any filter add the field it cannot be present in the response.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The same as you said, but content-length did not automatic update with the actual size.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Filter to provide the servlet with a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` which would override `getWriter` and `getOutputStream`. Both method would return wrappers to actual streams that count the characters written there.

Comment: Maybe too expensive for a get total size.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection FTW.

```
    public static Long getByteCount(final HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Field innerResponseField = ServletResponseWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("response");
        innerResponseField.setAccessible(true);
        innerResponseField.get(response);
        Object innerResponse = innerResponseField.get(response);
        Field contentWrittenField = OnCommittedResponseWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("contentWritten");
        contentWrittenField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Long) contentWrittenField.get(innerResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where to get this OnCommittedResponseWrapper?

Comment: Worked for me, however I've used contentWrittenField.get(response); Object innerResponse was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do the monitoring of such basic HTTP stuff yourself, Tomcat does it for you:

Add the [AccessLogValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging) to your `server.xml` and voila you have the response size given by the `%b` variable in the access logs.

Comment: Thx, Actually i want control this per user, so that I want process this in filter. it's really hard doing this in AccessLogValve .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get total size of HttpServletRequest using JavaEE API.